# Carry flag of the operation 0 - 1 in 8 bit register

Tags: assembly, x86, carryflag, eflags

I tried the following code in emu 80x86 IDE :

```
mov al,0h
sub al,1h
```

In the output it displays in the emulator `al=FF` and I did understand it, but what I didn't understand is why in the flags section `cf=1`

Comment: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carry flag `CF` is used when CPU works with **unsigned integer** numbers (in 8bit registers they can have value between 00h and FFh).

When addition is performed and the result exceeds the maximal value FFh, `CF` signalizes that it happened, and that number 1 should be added to the register with higher order (`ah`).

When subtraction is performed and the result is below the minimal value 00h, `CF` signalizes that it happened and that number 1 should be borrowed (subtracted) from `ah`.

In your example code the result of subtracting 1h from the 0h in `al` is below the allowed minimal value, that's why CF is set.

Setting `cf=1` CPU indicates unsigned subtraction underflow.

If you look at those numbers as **signed integers**, their allowed range is -128 to +127 (80h to 7F) and overflow or underflow is signalized with different flag `of`. In your code the result (treated as signed number) is -1 (FFh) and this is within the allowed range (no overflow), so you should see in emulator that `of=0`.